# Show that the map $\alpha:\mathbb{Z}_n\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ by $s\to sr$ where $r\in U(n)$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: group-theory

$\alpha :\mathbb{Z}\_n\to\mathbb{Z}\_n$ by $s\to sr$ where $r\in U(n)$ is an automorphism.

Homomorphism:
$ \alpha(s+t)=r(s+t)=rs+rt=\alpha(s)+\alpha(r)$

Injective:

Suppose $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$

Then $rx=ry\iff x=y$

Im not sure how to show surjectivity however.

Also I'm not sure how this could be an isomorphism as $\alpha(1)=r$ so its not mapping the identity to the identity.

Comment: Consider $ r|n.$

Comment: @Minz Notice that $r\in U(n)$, which means $r$ is co-prime to $n$.

Comment: @ awllower Thanks, I did not know the meaning of the notation $U(n).$ If $r$ is co-prime to $n$ then it has inverse modulo $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a homomorphism to be an automorphism, it needs and it suffices for it to be bijective.

Since $r\in U(n)$, there is some $r'$ such that $r\cdot r'+n\cdot n'=1$, for some integer $n'$. Hence the map $\beta:\mathbb Z_n\rightarrow\mathbb Z_n$ given by $s\mapsto sr'$ is the inverse of $\alpha$. (Show this.) This shows that $\alpha$ is bijective, and hence an automorphism.

---

As to your question regarding why it does not send $1$ to $1$, notice that the identity of $\mathbb Z_n$ is $1_{\mathbb Z_n}=0+n\mathbb Z$, which is sent to the identity by $\alpha$.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Directly find the inverse homomorphism. It is also the multiplication by a unit. Can you find which?